# Is showing $f(x)>g(x)$ enough to prove that $f(x)$ increases faster than $g(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

is showing $f(x)>g(x)$ enough to prove that $f(x)$ increases faster than $g(x)$ for almost all $x$?

Comment: What do you mean by "increases faster"?

Comment: $x^x$ for example "increases faster" than $x^3$

Comment: Well, then $x+1$ is always bigger than $x$ but they increase at the same rate.

Comment: I have to observe $f'$ i figured

Comment: Before you can  settle this you need to  _define_  "increases faster". Just giving one example is not  a definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, take $\color{blue}{f(x)=1}$ and $\color{red}{g(x)=1-{1\over 2^x}}$

[image]

---

If $f'(x)-g'(x)>0$ then this would be true.

Comment: So what would I need to prove?

Comment: Do I have to use $f'$?

Answer (score 9):

Consider $g(x)=-e^{-x}$.  That increases to $0$.

Now take $f(x)=e^{-x}$.  That decreases to $0$.

Clearly $$f(x)>g(x)$$

Thus, knowing that $f$ is bigger than an increasing function $g$ doesn't even prove that $f$ is increasing.

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f(x) = x+17$ and $g(x) = x.$ They increase at the same rate everywhere for any reasonable definition, yet $f > g.$

Comment: I guess I have to use $f'$?

Comment: Well, if your definition of "increase faster" is $f' > g',$ which is a very reasonable definition, then yes, just by definition!

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ increases more quickly than $g$, that simply means the function $f-g$ is increasing. So you want to show that $(f-g)'>0$

Your question therefore boils down to, is:

$$f-g>0\implies (f-g)'>0$$
true?

You can define $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ to give the statement:
$$h(x)>0\implies h'(x)>0$$
f0r which I supply $h:\Bbb R^+ \mapsto \Bbb R: h(x)=\frac1x$ as an adequate counterexample.